# only print last two value of linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

Here is my Node class

```
public class listNode {
String data;
listNode next;

     public listNode(String data, listNode next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
     }       

     public String toString(){
        return data;
     }
}
```

Hers is my List class

```
public class List {
listNode head;

    public List(){
        head = null;
    }

    public void addLast(String target){
        if(head == null){
            head = new listNode(target,head);
        }
        while(head.next != null){
            head = head.next;
        }
        head.next = new listNode(target,null);
    } 
}
```

print method:

```
public void print(){
    while(head != null){
        System.out.println(head.toString());
        head = head.next;
    }
}
```

When I use this method at main function, it always only print the last two value of the linked list, and I am so confused.

example:

```
l1.addLast("a");
l1.addLast("b");
l1.addLast("c");
```

it only prints

```
b,c
```

Comment: Show the code that actually does the printing.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is incorrect. You should not change the head object. Use a different object.

```
while(head.next != null){
            head = head.next;
}
```

It should be like:

```
class List {
listNode head;

    public List(){
        head = null;
    }

    public void addLast(String target){
        if(head == null){
            head = new listNode(target,head);
        }
        else {
            listNode last = head;
            while(last.next != null){
                last = last.next;
            }
            last.next = new listNode(target,null);  
        }

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 mistakes.

```
public void addLast(String target){
    if(head == null){
        head = new listNode(target,head);
        return; // Mistake 1 - you need to return here - nothing more is needed. 
        // If you don't return. addLast will create 2 listNode's for the first entry.
    }

    listNode h = head; // Mistake 2 - Use a temp instead of head. head will 
                  //no longer point to the start otherwise.

    while(h.next != null)
    {
        h = h.next;
    }
    h.next = new listNode(target,null);
}
```

The Mistakes are pointed to in the comments.

The first mistake isn't serious. The 2nd one is.